# xsd Complex Types with Mixed Content

Tags: xml, xsd

I am reading [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_complex_mixed.asp) and it states that to get an xml like this:

```
<letter>
  Dear Mr.<name>John Smith</name>.
  Your order <orderid>1032</orderid>
  will be shipped on <shipdate>2001-07-13</shipdate>.
</letter>
```

you need this xml schema definition:

```
<xs:element name="letter">
  <xs:complexType mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="orderid" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
      <xs:element name="shipdate" type="xs:date"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

But I see that is not completely correct.
It defines the name, orderid, and shiptdate elements but it didn't define the plain text like `Dear Mr.`, `Your order` and `will be shipped on`

The only `xs:string` type has been assigned to the `name` element.

Could you help me understanding that please?

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's what the `mixed="true"` does - it permits arbitrary text around and between the declared elements of the complex type. The elements must appear in the required sequence but there can be any text in between.

Comment: Though the tutorial already has a note for that, but I didn't look carefully. Thanks for your answer